# How to href to an other view without back button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a side menu like this one: 
[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview)

My problem is, if i try to href from one view to an other, i get a back button i dont wont...

For example:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <a href="#/app/search"> Test </a>
</ion-content>
```

[image: Href]
[image: The back button]

I hope you can help me,
thank you and happy new year ;)

Comment: My code looks like the example i posted:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understood you question correctly, but you can get rid of Back button by going into Plunker files, menu.html, and taking out line 5 with the code:

```
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
```

Comment: Ok, that was easy :D
Thank you ;)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped